# Am using bootstrap.js for tabs. but i couldnt do ajax request to load the links when the tab is clicked

Tags: ajax, tabs, twitter-bootstrap

My html

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
      <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/contacts" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/follows/friends_list" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/follows/awaiting_request" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
    </ul>
```

```
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">

      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">

      </div>
```

My javascript code :

```
 $('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault()
    var loadurl = $(this).attr('href')
    var targ = $(this).attr('data-target')

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {

      $(targ).html(data)
      });

    $(this).tab('show')
     return false;

 });
```

I have given links for tabs respectively. But i couldnt render those links in the page when a tab is clicked..
Could anyone please help me out of this.

Comment: whats about making an on() instead of an click. This means, all later changes on the dom will be detected as well.

Comment: ya i did change but that dnt help :(

Answer (score 4):

Seems to work fine for me:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/2eTSL/)

The only code that I added to yours (aside from using some gists for the ajax calls) was putting the tab panes inside a `<div class="tab-content">`.